# Data range in Google Sheets with last row

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, I'd like to set up a pie chart which uses the data from across my very last row.

[image]

How would I phrase this data range selection for `H(Last Row):L(Last Row)`?

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95538/is-there-a-constant-to-represent-last-row-of-a-column-in-google-spreadsheet/100873#100873

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),A:A)` gives you the value of the last row in `A`

Comment: It looks like I may have to store these values in a cell to use with the chart rather than using the query directly.

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets does not support indirect ranges (such as formulas) in **Select a data range** field. you will need to set up some auxiliary columns/rows to filter out what you need and then reference it with regular range reference.

to "harvest" the last row (`H(Last Row):L(Last Row)`) use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MAX(ROW(A:A)), 8, 4)&":"&ADDRESS(MAX(ROW(A:A)), 12, 4))
```

---

**`H2:L`** is what you seek if you want to define a range that has no end and starts from the second row. by not including the last digit the range gets to "infinity".

Comment: `H2:L` throws `One row required`. I'm hoping that I don't have to use additional cells to store the query, although I could tuck these away into another sheet.